# How can the height (or width) of an entire table be changed in one motion/keystroke in Indesign?

Tags: adobe-indesign, tables

How can the height (or width) of an entire table be changed in one motion/keystroke in Indesign similarly to they way it works in Quark where the size can be changed by dragging a table point? I don't want to have to select and change the size of each individual row (or column). It seems like there should be an easier way.

Answer (score 2):

Resize tables the same way you would any other object.  You can scale the entire table, by holding down <kbd>Shift</kbd> (as I have done), or you can adjust the height and width independently.

- Use your Selection Tool (V)
- Hold <kbd>⌘</kbd> (I'm on Mac, but I'd imagine that it's <kbd>CTRL</kbd> on Windows) and resize your table accordingly

[image: animation]

Answer (score 1):

You could do what John said, or you could click the top left corner of the table (blue dot in my image) to select the entire table, ie. all the rows and columns in the table.

Then you can play around with the options hightlighted in pink, which give you instant control to all row heights and all column widths. More info on how these options work can be researched online.

[image: screenshot]